# Regex to remove certain characters not working on json string obtained from pojo using gson

Tags: java, regex, gson

I am using gson to convert pojo to json string. On that string I want to remove certain characters and then want to convert back to pojo. My goal is to remove those characters from pojo. I want this function to be generic as this will be used on different type of pojos.

I have tried using jackson and gson both to convert pojo to string but none of them worked

```
public <T> T sanitise(T object, Class<T> class){
    return gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(object).replaceAll("[\\s]", ""), class);
}
```

I am getting this : `{"field1":"entry","field2":"\tentry\t","field3":"entry\tentry","field4":["\tentry\t","\tentry\tentry\t","entry"]}` output from `gson.toJson(pojo, pojoClass)`.

I want this :
 `{"field1":"entry","field2":"entry","field3":"entryentry","field4":["entry","entryentry","entry"]}` .

pojo is object of some pojoClass.

`.replaceAll("[\\s]", "")` works when I pass string `"\t\r\ndummy"` but not working with output of `gson.toJson()`

Comment: Try `.replaceAll("[\s]", "")`

Comment: as I have mentioned i ran this ```replaceAll("[\\s]", "")``` with String s = "\t\rdummy\n" and it worked but don't know why not working with output of toJson

Comment: you have mentioned??? I can't see any mention that it worked (before editing after this comment).... what is the result of `gson.toJson(object)`?

Comment: sorry, missed to mention it just updated.

Comment: ```{"field1":"entry","field2":"\tentry\t","field3":"entry\tentry","field4":["\tentry\t","\tentry\tentry\t","entry"]}``` output of ```gson.toJson(pojo, pojoClass)```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? **Edit** the question and show what you get and what you expected. Don't show in a comment. Make the question be complete by itself.

Comment: updated what is expected and what i got

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say it works when you pass Java string literal `"\t\r\ndummy"`, but that's because the `\t`, `\r`, and `\n` have been converted to `TAB`, `CR`, and `LF` characters by the Java compiler, resulting in string `<TAB><CR><LF>dummy`.

You say it doesn't work when using regex `"\\s"` with input that contains `"field2":"\tentry\t"`, but that's because the `\t` there is the two characters `\` and `t`, not the `TAB` character.

If you want to eliminate the *text* `\t`, then you need regex `"\\\\t"`, which is a Java string literal for the regex `\\t`, which means the `\` character followed by the `t` character.

Use `replaceAll("\\\\t", "")` instead of `replaceAll("[\\s]", "")`.

Comment: thanks this was the case, so in my case I have to write replace all for all characters which follow ```[\\s]``` like you mentioned for eg. ```"\\\\n"```, etc. or is there any other way

Comment: @cat `" |\\\\[trn]"` i.e. a space, or a ``\`` character followed by a `t`, `r`, or `n` letter. There is really no need to match the rest of what `\\s` does.